# ModelMapper - Map a DTO's property inside an Entity that has a Relationship that has this property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Good Morning

I am using the ModelMapper to map the DTOs to the Entities and vice versa and related to this I have one question.

1) When I'm getting SonDTO from SonController, I need to map the long motherId to Entity Son, but there I have the Entity Mother mother making the relationship and that has the id internally.
So how do I map this SonDTO motherId into the Entity Mother mother and vice versa?

Below the classes:

```java
class SonDTO {
    long id;
    String name;
    int age;
    long motherId;
}
```

```java
class MotherDTO{
    long id;
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Long> sonsId;
    List<String> sonsName;
}
```

```java
@Entity
class Mother{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "age")
   private int age;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mother", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
   List<Son> sons;

}
```

```java
@Entity
class Son{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "age")
   private int age;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "mother_id")
   private Mother mother;
}
```

Comment: what issue are you facing here??

Comment: I am trying to map using modelMapper the motherId inside the SonDTO into the Mother Entity that has this property but I couldn't do

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `PropertyMap` for your entity and add it to the `ModelMapper`.

```
PropertyMap<Mother, MotherDTO> motherMap = new PropertyMap<Mother, MotherDTO>() {
     protected void configure() {
         map().setSonsId(source.getSons()...//here is your choice of coding
         // you can either use streams or simple for loops to transform the
         // entity into a List<Long> 
         );
         //other attributes here
     }
};
```

and eventually:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(motherMap);
```

You don't have to create a mapping for the `SonDTO` object because the modelMapper is looking through your attributes' name and uses a default matching strategy and `SonDTO`'s attributes name are just enough to not use another strategies and match the correct source (`Son`) attributes.

Links:

1) Matching Process (*very important*) : [here](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/how-it-works/#matching-process)

2) Matching Strategies (*very important*) : [here](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies)

3) Example (*important*) : [here](http://modelmapper.org/examples/flattening/#example-1).  (Please pay attention here at the attribute naming.)