# how to display DTO correctly in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two Entities in my spring boot application. I am working with dtos and displaying my dto in the end. But I am getting the wrong output from my getRequest. My first entity is MeetingSetting which can have multiple MeetingTimes and inside MeetingTime I have meetingName as a foreign key. I want to display meetingTime like this:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2021-06-31",
        "startTime": "15:30",
        "endTime": "16:30",
        "meetingName": "Test"
            
}
```

But I am getting instead this one:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2021-06-31",
        "startTime": "15:30",
        "endTime": "16:30",
        "meetingName": {
            "id": 1,
            "meetingName": "Tewasddweewrst2",
            "meetingUrl": null,
            "meetingPw": ""
        }
}
```

Could someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

MeetingSetting Entity::

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "meeting_settings")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    public class MeetingsSetting implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
        private String meetingName;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_url")
        private String meetingUrl;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
        private String meetingPw;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingSettingDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingSettingDTO {


    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    private String meetingName;

    @NotNull
    private String meetingUrl;

    @NotNull
    private String meetingPw;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime;
}
```

MeetingTimeEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" , referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

MeetingTimeDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTimeDTO {


    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String date;

    @NotNull
    private String startTime;
    @NotNull
    private String endTime;

    private MeetingSettingDTO meetingName;

}
```

In my service I am first getting MeetingTime as an entity from my repository then converting it to DTO and returning it for my controller:

```
    @Service
    public class MeetingTimeService {
    
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    
        @Autowired
        MeetingTimeRepository meetingTimeRepository;
    
                public List<MeetingTimeDTO> findAllMeetingTimes(){
                    List<MeetingTime> meetingTimeList =  meetingTimeRepository.findAll();
                    return meetingTimeList.stream()
                            .map(this::convertToDto)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    
    
                }
        private MeetingTimeDTO convertToDto(MeetingTime meetingTime) {
            MeetingTimeDTO meetingTimeDTO = modelMapper.map(meetingTime, MeetingTimeDTO.class);
            return meetingTimeDTO;
        }

}
```

Controller:

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/" )
        public List<MeetingTimeDTO> getAllTimes() {
    return meetingTimeService.findAllMeetingTimes();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In MeetingTimeDTO:

```
private MeetingSettingDTO meetingName;
```

The type needs to be changed to:

```
    private string meetingName;
```

I have not worked with ModelMapper so cannot help you with how to map a specific field from the related object but this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826669/modelmapper-map-a-dtos-property-inside-an-entity-that-has-a-relationship-that) seems to provide the info needed.